# WPF DataGrid Thumb opacity without assigning the whole scrollbar style

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

Is it possible to set WPF data grid scrollbar thumb opacity **without changing the whole scrollbar template**? I've been searching but what I've seen it was quite complex solutions based on setting up the whole scrollbar template, whereas I just need to change only one property. What I've tried so far is

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

does not work, and

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Setter Property="Track.Thumb.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

gives "nested types are not supported error".

Or, may be it is possible from code-behind to write something like

```
myGrid.VerticalScrollBar.Track.Thumb.Opacity = 0.5;
```

(but the porblem is that grid has no such property..)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the solution of CrimsonX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) to get the the `ScrollBar` at runtime by it's name *PART_VerticalScrollBar*:

```
ScrollBar scrollBar = FindChild<ScrollBar>(myGrid, "PART_VerticalScrollBar");
scrollBar.Track.Thumb.Opacity = 0.1;
```

Note this only works if the `Window` is already rendered. This means it could be possible to set the opaticity in code behind after rendering. One way to do this is by overriding:

```
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Great, it works! In my case it is a UserControl so instead of OnContentRendered I've subscribed to LayoutUpdated event. Thanks a lot!